# How assign max value of subtotal to the interval of the horizontal axis in line graph of ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I want assign max value of subtotal of a field to the interval of the horizontal axis.

for eg There is a column name newsub which has subtotal sum(newsub). I want to assign max value of sum(newsub) to the interval of vertical axis in the line graph. I tried interval: =Max(Sum(Fields!Sales.Value,"Dataset1")), =Max(Sum(Fields!Sales.Value,"groupbydate"))

Answer (score 0):

Thew easiest way is to calculate this value in the dataset as an additional column. Then the expression for the axis max value would be something like

```
=FIRST(Fields!MyMaxValueColumn.Value, "MyDataset")
```